# Spring MockMVC test with JSON content is throwing NullPointerException from Spring code

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a small Spring MVC project. I'm writing MockMvc tests for it. Most of them work, but this one (the first one I've tried with a plain JSON body) is giving me trouble. I keep getting a NullPointerException from deep within Spring. I tried debugging through it, but eventually ran out of attached Spring source code without getting any closer to an answer.

My JSON block is captured from a live user test, which works fine. But in the test, it throws NPE. If I modify the JSON block to be malformed (IE, add an extra comma somewhere), then it throws a 400 Bad Request, as expected. Remove the extra comma, go back to NPE. Making the block invalid (IE, making a field null which is marked @NotNull in my domain object) does not give the expected 400 Bad Request. It just stays with the NPE.

All my other tests so far have been for controllers which just use query string params, and have worked fine. Also, I have one which due to browser restrictions on our customer's side must embed its JSON in a POST param (IE, "json = "{blah:blah}"), which I pull out and manually parse. That works fine, too.

### Controller:

```
@RestController
public class SaveController {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/path/to/controller", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('myRole', 'myAdminRole')")
    public void updateThing(@Valid @RequestBody MyThing myThing) throws IOException {
        myDao.updateMyThing(myThing);
    }
}
```

### Base test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestDataAccessConfiguration.class, TestApplicationConfiguration.class})
public abstract class AbstractSpringTestCase {
    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

### Test:

```
public class SaveControllerTest extends AbstractSpringTestCase {
    @Mock
    private MyDao myDao;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private SaveController classUnderTest;

    private static final JSON = "<a big JSON string captured from (working) production>";

    @Test
    public void testHappyPath() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/path/to/controller")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

### Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:170)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:145)
    at SaveControllerTest.testHappyPath(SaveControllerTest.java)
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

In order to send a request body using Spring MockMvc you must map the @RequestBody object as a json string.

Here's an example:

SingupController:

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public @ResponseBody
RealityKeeper createUser(@RequestBody SignupRequest signupRequest) {
    System.out.println("SignupRequest: " + signupRequest);
    String password = signupRequest.getPassword();
    String username = signupRequest.getUsername();
    String encoded = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    RealityKeeper realityKeeper = new RealityKeeper(username, encoded);
    return repository.save(realityKeeper);
}
```

SignupControllerTest:

```
@Test
public void createUser() throws Exception {
    SignupRequest signupRequest = new SignupRequest("foo", "bar");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
    ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String requestJson=ow.writeValueAsString(signupRequest);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/signup")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(requestJson))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

}
```

Using jackson's object mapper you can turn a pojo into a json string and pass it to the mockMvc content method.

Hope this helps